# Could not process Bank Of America debit or credit cards -> Card declined by issuer

Tags: php, authorize.net

We’ve just implemented Authorize.net on our new platform to replace our old one (braintree).

We have done some tests, from the charge credit card example that we adapted to our code.
**It worked *perfectly fine* with Chase and Capital One debits card but didn’t work on any of bank of america debit and credit cards** for some mysterious reasons. When looking on my profile I can read "Card declined by issuer”. I called the bank and they said the card wasn’t activated (When you receive a new card you need to activate it first). But all the card we’ve tried have been activated for long and we already processed payments online with (it also work on Braintree).

I went to my merchant service representative but they haven’t been able to help me. Am I doing something wrong? Did you hear about similar issues ? I’m concerned for other issues with banks when turning this thing live.

Here is my piece of code :

`

```
            // Common setup for API credentials  
    $merchantAuthentication = new AnetAPI\MerchantAuthenticationType();   
    $merchantAuthentication->setName($this->ci->config->item('AUTHNETAPILOGINID'));   
    $merchantAuthentication->setTransactionKey($this->ci->config->item('AUTHNETKEY'));   
            $refId = 'ref' . time();

    // Remove potential white spaces
    $ccn = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $ccn);

    // Create the payment data for a credit card
    $creditCard = new AnetAPI\CreditCardType();
    $creditCard->setCardNumber( intval( $ccn ) );
    $creditCard->setExpirationDate( $exp );
    $creditCard->setCardCode( $cvc );
    $paymentOne = new AnetAPI\PaymentType();
    $paymentOne->setCreditCard($creditCard);

    $order = new AnetAPI\OrderType();
    $order->setDescription("Ticket");

    // Create a transaction
    $transactionRequestType = new AnetAPI\TransactionRequestType();
    $transactionRequestType->setTransactionType("authCaptureTransaction");   
    $transactionRequestType->setAmount( $amount );
    $transactionRequestType->setOrder( $order );
    $transactionRequestType->setPayment($paymentOne);

    $request = new AnetAPI\CreateTransactionRequest();
    $request->setMerchantAuthentication($merchantAuthentication);
    $request->setRefId( $refId );
    $request->setTransactionRequest($transactionRequestType);
    $controller = new AnetController\CreateTransactionController($request);
    $response_api = $controller->executeWithApiResponse(\net\authorize\api\constants\ANetEnvironment::PRODUCTION);   

    if ($response_api != null)
    { // more code }`
```

I was hoping you could help me debut if it’s coming from here. Should I add the postal code or address to make sure it’s not a security issue on their end ? Where could that come from ? I’m a little lost on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Considering your initial description of the conversation with said bank I' say: if they claim that card has not been activated and you can prove that indeed the card _had_ been activated, then they will have to dig deeper on their side...

Comment: Agreed, I went to a branch and talked to them. They are investigating this issue but didn’t have a solution for that. In the meantime, trying to process the exact same transaction on our platform with Braintree work just fine.